# Error al invocar el getPort de un wsdl con SpringBoot 2.7.12 Y javax

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, jax-ws

Tengo un problema con la implementación del servicio rest y una librería local hecha a partir de un WSDL y el comando wsimport basado en Springboot y Apache CXF. Al intentar usar la librería se genera el siguiente error.

```
2023-07-10 18:31:36,859 [,,,,,][http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO   [o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] Creating Service {http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/}WSCommonEmailEndPoint from WSDL: https://wsPruebas201.local.example.corp:8080/WarWSCommonEmail/WSCommonEmailEndPoint/WSCommonEmailEndPoint.wsdl
2023-07-10 18:31:37,153 [,,,,,][http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR  [o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException] with root cause
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:282)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1142)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:144)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:245)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:499)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:358)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:492)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:358)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:349)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
    at example.ban.commonemail.ws.wsdl.WSCommonEmailEndPoint.getCommonEmailServicePort(WSCommonEmailEndPoint.java:98)
```

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "WSCommonEmailEndPoint", targetNamespace = "http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", wsdlLocation = "https://wsPruebas201.local.example.corp:8080/WarWSCommonEmail/WSCommonEmailEndPoint/WSCommonEmailEndPoint.wsdl")
public class WSCommonEmailEndPoint extends Service {

    private final static URL WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME = new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "WSCommonEmailEndPoint");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://wsPruebas201.local.example.corp:8080/WarWSCommonEmail/WSCommonEmailEndPoint/WSCommonEmailEndPoint.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME);
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME);
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "CommonEmailServicePort")
    public CommonEmailService getCommonEmailServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "CommonEmailServicePort"), CommonEmailService.class);
    }


    @WebEndpoint(name = "CommonEmailServicePort")
    public CommonEmailService getCommonEmailServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "CommonEmailServicePort"), CommonEmailService.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

Se esperaba que se ejecutara la invocación al WSDL webservice, no veo error en la clase WSCommonEmailEndPoint, tengo otro proyecto que consume un WSDL de forma similar.